# Android service does not stop until calling activity is killed

Tags: java, android

I start a service that returns START_STICKY.

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view){
    boolean on = ((Switch) view).isChecked();
    boolean serviceRunning = isMyServiceRunning(MainService.class);
    if(on && !serviceRunning){
        startService(new Intent("com.banda.MainService"));
    }else if(!on && serviceRunning){
        stopGlyphService();
    }
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then when I call

```
private void stopGlyphService(){
    stopService(new Intent("com.banda.MainService"));
}
```

The onDestroy() on the service is called, but the service keeps running. The next time when i click the toggle button, the *isMyServiceRunning()* returns false, and another instance of the service is started.

When I close the main activity, and kill the application by pulling it out of app tray, the services, whose onDestroy() got called, finally stop working.

onDestroy() in MainService:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    System.out.println("Service stopping");
    this.stopSelf();
}
```

In short:

- I need to start a service that keeps running after main activity is
  killed (START_STICKY).
- I need to be able to stop the service after closing the main activity
  and opening it again and killing the service then.
- I need the service to be stopped even if the main activity is not
  closed, so I don't get multiple instances running at once.

Thank you.

Comment: in your stopGlyphService()-Mehtod you have to stop the intent of the running intent and not create a new one.

Comment: But the onDestroy() of the service is called and the service stops when the activity is killed. Also I need to be able to stop the main activity and start it again, therefore losing the instance of the intent that started the service.

Comment: I also tried serializing the intent and de-serializing it for use in stopService()